# iOS Get Signal Strength in Swift (Core Telephony)

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, core-telephony, signal-strength

I'm new to iOS, and am learning to code with Swift. My app needs to measure the signal strength. I've found this code working on Objective-C/C, and need some help to implement on Swift. Here is what I got. Hope someone can help me finish it.

**OBJECTIVE C**

```
    int getSignalStrength()
    {
       void *libHandle = dlopen("/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony", RTLD_LAZY);
       int (*CTGetSignalStrength)();
       CTGetSignalStrength = dlsym(libHandle, "CTGetSignalStrength");
       if( CTGetSignalStrength == NULL) NSLog(@"Could not find CTGetSignalStrength");
       int result = CTGetSignalStrength();
       dlclose(libHandle);
       return result;
    }
```

**SWIFT**

```
    func getSignalStrength()->Int{
       var result : Int! = 0
       let libHandle = dlopen ("/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony", RTD_LAZY)
       ** help **
       var CTGetSignalStrength = dlsym(libHandle, "CTGetSignalStrength")
       if (CTGetSignalStrength != nil){
           result = CTGetSignalStrength()
       }
       dlclose(libHandle)
       return result
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you implement it as class method in obj-c class?

Comment: Im trying to make it a Swift-only app.

Comment: Did you solve it? There is just no way to do it? :(

Answer (score 2):

Don't use dlopen to load CoreTelephony. Use `import CoreTelephony` at the top of your Swift file. Then just use CTGetSignalStrength as if it were any other function.

Comment: Then there is an error : Use of unresolved identifier 'CTGetSignalStrength'

Comment: Ah, it's a private API. I don't think it's possible to use private APIs directly from Swift. However, you can keep the working Objective-C code and use it from Swift.

Answer (score 2):

Swift 3 Solution

```
import CoreTelephony
import Darwin

    static func getSignalStrength()->Int{
        var result : Int = 0
        //int CTGetSignalStrength();
        let libHandle = dlopen ("/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony", RTLD_NOW)
        let CTGetSignalStrength2 = dlsym(libHandle, "CTGetSignalStrength")

        typealias CFunction = @convention(c) () -> Int

        if (CTGetSignalStrength2 != nil) {
            let fun = unsafeBitCast(CTGetSignalStrength2!, to: CFunction.self)
            let result = fun()
            return result;
            print("!!!!result \(result)")
        } 
     return -1
 }
```

Comment: This function always returns 100 for me on iOS11, does it still work for you on iOS11?

Comment: No unfortunately this solution doesn't work anymore since iOS11.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Do you by any chance know of a method that works on iOS11 as well?

Comment: Nothing that I know of, I can refer you to this video which explains how to use builtin field tester app: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GBCi2zeSra4 

Only way to figure this out I think is to decompile field tester app.