# Determining iOS Signal Strength

Tags: ios, swift, signal-strength

Is there a way to determine the signal strength of an iOS device?

I found this: [iOS Get Signal Strength in Swift (Core Telephony)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25429732/ios-get-signal-strength-in-swift-core-telephony)

But there didn't seem to be a solution here. Has an API been written for this?

Keep in mind, I need the solution to be valid for sale on the app store so it can't use any private libraries.

Comment: take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14604273/accurately-reading-of-iphone-signal-strength - it is possible to call objective-c code from swift, as long as you set up the appropriate bridging headers and import the header file of your objective-c method: `#import "MyObjectiveCCode.h"`

Comment: This might sound stupid but I've never written any Objective-C code. Will I need to create a header and main file for the class?